# Reading csv using csvread command in h2 database

Tags: csv, h2

I have list of csv files which are stored in one folder.

Is it possible to read all the csv inside the folder using csvread command in h2 database.
Also the number of csv files in folder are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to

- concatenate the files,
- run multiple queries,
- run a ['union' query](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#select), or
- write a [file system abstraction](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system) that makes the files appear as one file

Comment: Can you give an example where we can concatenate the files and then use it in csvread function

Comment: Well, concatenate the file for example using a shell script (`cat input_file* >> out.txt`)

Comment: Hi Thomas can u give an example for using mutiple csv within csvread command using concatenation